# How do I convert an absolute Posix path to a Windows path in Python's pathlib?

Tags: python, pathlib

I'm running Python 3.9 on Windows. I have an absolute Posix path, such as:

> '/c/Program Files/clang-format'

I happened to have obtained this by running `os.system('which clang-format')`, but no matter.

I want to convert this to a Windows path so that I can call `os.system(path_to_exe)`. I don't know why it's giving me Posix paths, but it can't consume Posix paths. But whatever.

I can't find any equivalent to the `.as_posix()` function for converting a path from Posix to Windows. What should I do? And note that it's not as simple as replacing forward slash with backslash (which isn't necessary in modern Windows anyway) because these are absolute paths, so something needs to stick a C: in there.

Comment: How about simply replacing `/c/` with `C:/`?

Comment: The "which" command does not exist by default in Windows. Are you using MinGW? In MinGW the paths are represented like that (e.g. `/c/` folder instead of `C:/` drive)

Comment: Does `os.system('/c/Program Files/clang-format --version')` raise an error?

Comment: Yes, that command raises an error: 'The system cannot find the path specified.' If I change it to 'C:/Pro...' then the error is "'C:/Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,..." So changing '/c' to 'C:/' is insufficient because of the spaces. Why is there no as_windows() function in pathlib? Seems like an obvious and glaring asymmetry.

Comment: I'm using git bash, which I think might be based on MinGW. So sure, that's why it provides me a Posix path in the 'which' command. But it won't accept a Posix path in the clang-format command. This is pretty darn lame!

Comment: How about using functions of the subprocess module? 
https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/subprocess.html  Or maybe you want to use shlex.quote? https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/shlex.html

Comment: [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) could be helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Windows NT format path using the `os.path` module, and you can isolate the drive by using the `os.path.splitdrive` function. This only gets you halfway there; you still have to lop off the posix base `/c/` and reconstruct the path.

I've used `posixpath` to deal with the posix structure returned in mingw.

So something like:

```py
import os
import posixpath

path_to_exe = str(os.system('which clang-format'))
# > '/c/Program Files/clang-format'

drive = os.path.splitdrive(os.path.abspath('.'))[0]
# > 'C:'

# break down the posix path storing it in reverse order
root, ext = posixpath.split(path_to_exe)

rev_path = []
rev_path.append(ext)

while (root != '/c'):
    root, ext = posixpath.split(root)
    rev_path.append(ext)
    
# construct the forward path
path = os.path.join(drive, os.sep)
rev_path.reverse()

for p in rev_path:
    path = os.path.join(path, p)

# path = "C:\\Program Files\\clang-format"
```

It's pretty gross, but should get you there.

Note that this assumes you're running the Python code on the same drive as your `clang-format` executable.